# SQL - create a ' dynamic/ dependant' table

Tags: mysql, sql

is it possible to create a table in MySQL (phpmyadmin ) which is the result of certain queries ( joining existing tables data ).

**e.g**   table1 and table2 ( both have a foreign key, related info ect.. ) so instead of making a query every time which is annoying, i wonder if i can create a table3  that is 'dependent' of these tables.

I know this can be achieved for example using a php script (browser), but does it work itself in phpmyadmin ?

Comment: Maybe using View? if I got you right

Comment: i have a simple script that prints a query.. I was wondering, If i could instead create the table itself in phpmyadmin using the queries.. View? I will check that out.. thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL has basically three different ways to do what you want.

```
1. Stored Procedures
2. Functions
3. Views
```

Which to use depends upon your needs as they all have various cost and benefits.  For most simple cases, any of the three can be made to work.